# Preemptible workers on dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I saw in the dataproc docs that preemptible workers shouldn’t be used for storage. Is this why their boot disks are kept low in size? Ie should I be guaranteeing that the permanent workers have enough storage for my data during processing? Any detailed guidance on how to best use the preemptible workers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a good reference: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/compute/preemptible-vms. Also consider reading more about Preemptible VMs here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible

1) Preemptible VMs are *not* used for HDFS storage. Preemptible VMs are preempted every 24 hours (often several at the same time), and are not guaranteed to come back. If HDFS blocks were kept on PVMs, it's pretty likely that your data will be unavailable.

That being said, if you use GCS for storage, you don't need to worry about the on-cluster HDFS.

2) Yes, this is why PVM boot disks are smaller by default. As the docs say, you can override the default and make it larger. Persistent Disk performance scales with size (I'll admit that's confusing), so if you are running shuffle-heavy jobs (like SQL-type queries), you may want to increase it. If you're running CPU-bound jobs (like machine learning), it's probably not a big deal. You'll just have to play with disk size to see what works for you.

3) Yes, you should guarantee that the primary workers have enough space for all HDFS data.

4) I will reach out to our PM/docs writer on adding better guidance for PVMs. From what I've heard, a good rule of thumb is to ensure you don't have more than 50% of your cluster be PVMs.

If PVMs get preempted while a job is running, the job progress will be set back. Not only will in-progress tasks fail, but shuffle data from finished tasks will be lost. Again, you'll have to experiment to see what works for you.

Since tasks are likely to fail when using preemptible VMs, you will likely need to bump up task retries and app master retries.

YARN:

- yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts (defaults to 2)

Mapreduce:

- mapreduce.map.maxattempts (defaults to 4)
- mapreduce.reduce.maxattempts (defaults to 4)

Spark:

- spark.task.maxFailures (default 4)
- spark.stage.maxConsecutiveAttempts (default 4)

You can set these properties when creating a cluster with --properties: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties.